# .NET Core install not found by Rider IDE

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core, rider

I get the following error when i try to create a new .net project in RIDER IDE:

> Can't detect .NET Core 1.0. Install .NET Core and restart Rider.

I have issue find command:

```
./usr/bin/dotnet
./opt/dotnet
./opt/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/1.1.0/dotnet
./opt/dotnet/dotnet
```

So I have tried setting the .NET path to both /opt/dotnet and /usr/bin/dotnet in Rider settings, without positive result.

My .NET version is: 1.0.0-preview2-1-003177

How can I make it work? I'm using Arch and installed dotnet from yaourt.

Answer (score 2):

1.0.0-preview2-* is too old for Rider. Use the release version. I think we have to write about that explicitly in error.